# Using fetch to set state before the page renders

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, auth0

I'm building a guard for a React component. The guard takes an Auth0 JWT and checks our API to see if that user exists in our database. If the user does exist, we set `userExists` to `true` and redirect them to `/dashboard`. If the user does not exist, we call `postUser` and send them to `/complete-profile`.

The problem I'm running into is that the page is rendering before `userExists` is properly being set by the fetch call. In other words, if I were to run the below code, the logs would read in this order:

1. USER DOES EXIST
2. FETCH CALLED 1

```
const SomeGuard: FC<SomeGuardProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  const isMountedRef = useIsMountedRef();

  const [userExists, setUserExists] = React.useState(true);

  const getUser = useCallback( async () => {
    try {
      var user_exists;
      fetch(`https://website.com/user`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer DFJKS54DUJ6DD.SDF2KJWEF4NKN3JKw4534.DFSKJ5HSKDJ6HF`,
          },
          method: 'GET',
        },
      ).then(response => {
        if (response.status===200) { // USER EXISTS
          console.log("FETCH CALLED 1")
          setUserExists(true);
        }
        else if (response.status===404) { // catch 404 -- USER NOT FOUND
          console.log("FETCH CALLED 2")
          setUserExists(false);
        }
        
        return response.json();
      })
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, [isMountedRef]);


  const postUser = useCallback( async () => {
    // assume this works and sends a POST request to our API
    // to create a user
  )}


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("STEP 1");
    getUser();
  }, [getUser]);



  if (isAuthenticated) {
    if (!userExists) {
      console.log("USER DOES NOT EXIST");
      postUser();
      return <Redirect to="/complete-profile" />;
    }
    else if (userExists) {
      console.log("USER DOES EXIST");
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
    }
  }

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    console.log("TRIED TO HIT DASHBOARD WITHOUT BEING LOGGED IN");
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};


SomeGuard.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};

export default SomeGuard;
```

Because it renders the page before the `fetch` is called, the value that I initially set `userExists` to always determines which page is rendered.

Please help! What am I missing here? How can I get the `fetch` call to update `userExists` before the page is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the initial value of `userExists` to something else, like `null`, so you can differentiate an unloaded page from a loaded and true / loaded and false page. Then, only render the children once `userExists` isn't null:

```
const [userExists, setUserExists] = React.useState(null);
```

```
if (isAuthenticated) {
    if (userExists === false) {
        console.log("USER DOES NOT EXIST");
        postUser();
        return <Redirect to="/complete-profile" />;
    }
    else if (userExists === true) {
        console.log("USER DOES EXIST");
        return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
    }
}
```

```
return userExists === null ? null : children;
```

Comment: The `return userExists === null ? null` should result in nothing being rendered while the async request is going on.